# question about mean of unbiased sample variance vs population variance

Tags: statistics

I'm having a basic question about Bessel's correction and hope someone would clarify for me. My understanding is, since unbiased sample variances $s$ removes bias, the mean of unbiased variances of all possible samples of a given sample size (that is, the expectation of unbiased variances of that given sample size) should be equal to population variance $\sigma^2$.

But using experiments on a population dataset (0,0,0,1,2,9) which has $\mu=2$ and $σ^2=10.33$ with sample size of 2 proves that it's still biased (higer than $\sigma^2$).

$$\frac{1}{30}\Sigma(s)=\frac{1}{30}\Sigma \frac{(x_1-\bar{x})^2+(x_2-\bar{x})^2)}{2-1}=12.4$$

12.4 > 10.33

Was my understanding wrong?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction#Source_of_bias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what this particular Wikipedia editor (who came up with this example) had in mind.

They write (with emphasis added by me), "if all possible samples of $n = 2$ are taken and this method is used, the average estimate will be $12.4$, same as **the sample variance** with Bessel's correction".

What do they mean by "the" sample variance? I suspect they mean to treat the entire population $(0,0,0,1,2,9)$ as a "sample" and compute its "variance" with $n-1$ rather than $n$ in the denominator. Indeed if we do that we get $12.4$ as the "sample variance" of $(0,0,0,1,2,9)$.

I find that a very unsatisfying explanation. I'm not convinced that it has much to do with the motivation of Bessel's correction.

---

We get a very different picture later in the same article, under the heading,
"Proof of Correctness".
Note that we assume the sample of $n$ observations have values
$x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and we define $\bar x = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i.$

From the first proof,

> ... To see this, note that when we pick $x_u$ and $x_v$ via $u,$ $v$ being integers selected independently and uniformly from $1$ to $n,$ a fraction $n/n^2 = 1/n$ of the time we will have $u = v$ and therefore the sampled squared difference is zero independent of the original distribution. The remaining $1-1/n$ of the time, the value of $E[(x_u-x_v)^2]$ is the expected squared difference between two independent observations from the original distribution. ...

This assumes that (for example) the first two observations in the sample, $x_1$ and $x_2$ ($u = 1 \neq v = 2$), are two "independent observations" from the original distribution. But if we require that the sampling be done without replacement, $x_1$ and $x_2$ will generally not be independent observations.

In the other two versions of a "proof of correctness", it is taken as a fact that
${\operatorname{Var}(\bar x)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}.$
This is true in general if the observations $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are all independent of each other, but not generally true if the observations are sampled without replacement from a finite population.

In summary, Bessel's correction rests on the assumption that if the sample is taken from a finite population, it is taken *with replacement*. And indeed if you take a sample of two observations from $(0,0,0,1,2,9)$ uniformly with replacement,
you will have $36$ equally likely outcomes (including nine instances of $(0,0),$ one each of $(1,1),$ $(1,2),$ and $(2,1),$ and so forth) whose average sample variance (with Bessel's correction in each sample variance) is $10.33333\ldots.$
And this is equal to the population variance of $(0,0,0,1,2,9)$ according to the standard definition of population variance.

---

Returning to the section that you looked at, it seems to be saying that if you take a sub-sample (without replacement) a sample of a population, you will (on average) get the same sample variance from the sub-sample as from the original sample.
This is an interesting observation, but I do not think it is really an intuitive explanation of the "source of bias".

I think a better explanation of the source of bias comes from the fact that $\bar x$ is the unique value of $x_0$ in the expression
$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_0)^2$
that minimizes the sum. So whenever $\bar x \neq \mu$ (which in most practical problems is almost all the time),
$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 < \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2,$
and it is **never** the case that
$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 > \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2.$
But $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2$ (if we knew how to compute it)
would be a truly unbiased estimate of the variance.
That's why we need to "correct" the sample variance upward from
$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2.$

---

One might object to the proofs of Bessel's correction (which rely on the independence of the observations in the sample) on the grounds that a typical sample from a finite population is taken without replacement and therefore is not independent.

One response is that samples from which we want to estimate population variance are not always selected from finite populations. For example, suppose we have a black box containing an unknown number of dice with unknown number of sides on each die, and the only way we can examine the contents of the box is to push a button, upon which the box shakes the dice thoroughly, lets them come to rest, and then reports the sum of the numbers that were "rolled" in this fashion. And suppose we can repeat this as many times as we want. Then a sample of $n$ button-push outcomes is sampled from a (theoretically) infinite space of possible button pushes.

Another response is that when the population is finite, it's typically much, much larger than the sample size, so while sampling without replacement technically gives a set of values that are not independent, the probability distribution of $x_n$ (given $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}$) will not be much different from the prior distribution of $x_n$ (which is equal to the prior distribution of $x_1,$ etc.).

If the sample size is actually a relatively large portion of the population,
for example if the sample is actually one third of the entire population
(as it is in the example of taking a sample of size two from $(0,0,0,1,2,9)$),
then a further correction is required.
There is a lot written about this with regard to the accuracy of the estimation of the mean (see [How does accuracy of a survey depend on sample size and population size?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/926478/139123) or look up "finite population correction factor"). Obviously it affects the estimate of the variance too, but I cannot point you to any good resources at this time.

Comment: "if the sample is taken from a finite population, it is taken with replacement" perfect clarification